# move std::ofstream writing pointer to a different location in a file

Tags: c++, file-io

when writing to a text file, using `std::ofstream::operator<<` I can either write from the **beginning** or the **end** of the file and are unable to write from the **middle**.

I have this text file.

```
##scores##
player1: 50
player2: 10
player3: 80
```

now, player2 just gains **40** points. and I want one able to write that in without touching the other players' scores. I could copy the whole text and then modify it inside my application but it feels a bit hacky and slow. I wondered if there are any better ways? kind of like:

```
std::ofstream::setpos(50);
```

Comment: [`seekp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp)?

Comment: If you are dealing with enough entries that generating the whole file at once from in-memory data is not in the cards, then you should probably be using an actual database file format/library like sqlite3.

Comment: Writing over formatted text in a file can get really tricky. It is often whole orders of magnitude easier to read in the file, update it in memory, and then write over the original file. If you have to inplace edit, you have to make sure whatever new information you write is exactly the same length as the what it overwrites. If it's too long, you're writing over the next line in the file. If it's too short, you leave garbage on the line. You can move stuff around if you have to, but know that it's much, much easier to make a file longer than it is to make the file shorter.